# Gulp not compiling LESS file in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, gulp

I'm still new to Gulp and have only used it once on a sample project but that was a few months ago. Now I'm trying to use it in a new Test app for work. At the moment all I'm looking to do is compile my Bootstrap.less with my styles.less and main.less in order to make a CSS file.

I went through the npm init to setup the package.json file. I then added a gulpfile.js with the following code into the root of my project.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Compiles LESS > CSS 
gulp.task('build-less', function () {
    return gulp.src('./Content/LESS/styles.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Content'));
});
```

I also ran all of the following npm commands.

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
npm install gulp-concat --save-dev
npm install gulp-uglify --save-dev
npm install del --save-dev
```

I've also created a Content\LESS folder that has the Bootstrap.less files as well as my custom less files.

This is my styles.less file.

```
@import "Bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "main";
```

This is all that's in my main.less file for now.

```
.voffset  { margin-top: 2px; }
.voffset1 { margin-top: 5px; }
.voffset2 { margin-top: 10px; }
.voffset3 { margin-top: 15px; }
.voffset4 { margin-top: 30px; }
.voffset5 { margin-top: 40px; }
.voffset6 { margin-top: 60px; }
.voffset7 { margin-top: 80px; }
.voffset8 { margin-top: 100px; }
.voffset9 { margin-top: 150px; }
```

When I open up the Task Runner Explorer in Visual Studio 2015 I'm expecting to see the "build-less" task but I don't see it. When I click on default I get an "Process terminated with code 1." which is probably correct since I don't have a "default" task.

[image]

Here is my folder structure. I'm trying to get the compiled .css file to go in to the Content folder.

[image]

Shouldn't I see my Task named "build-less"? Do I have to have a "default" task that runs my "build-less" task?

UPDATE

New error once Task showed up. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the return from your task:

```
gulp.task('build-less', function () {
    gulp.src('./Content/LESS/styles.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Content'));
```

On your updated question the issue is that you haven't define the `less`. You can do it by installing `gulp-less` and then in your gulpfile:
`var less = require('gulp-less')`

Comment: I'm still not seeing my "build-less" task in Task Runner. I thought I would see that and be able to right-click and run it. I've closed the Trask Runner and re-opened with no success.

Comment: Closing VS and opening it again I can now see the Task. However, running the Task gives and error "less is not defined". I attached a screen shot above. Anyone know why I would be getting that error?

Comment: Well did you define less? `var less = require('gulp-less')`. Of course you should install it first.

Comment: I did and tried it again but I'm still having issues. I'm going to have to move on and just use straight .css for now and come back to try it all again. I'm probably going to have to go back through my Gulp course to help out.

Comment: Did you install `gulp-less` and still getting the same issue?

Comment: yes, I installed "npm install gulp-less --save-dev" and "npm install less-plugin-autoprefix --save-dev" and put "var gulp = require('gulp-less')" at the top of my gulpfile.js. However, now in VS my Gulpfile.js in the Task Runner says "Failed to load" and restarting VS doesn't help. I'm going to come back and revisit the whole process again in the next day or so. I have to get a basic site up and running by tomorrow so I'm having to use just CSS at the moment. I definitely want to get LESS going...I just don't know if I should use Gulp or use the Visual Studio Web Essentials.

Comment: I got the autoprefix plugin idea from the video class I took.